# Calculate distribution of date differences in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

In our database each user has a `created_at` and `cancelled_at` date. How could I calculate the distribution of days active for users (that have a `cancelled_at` date present).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By distribution, I would expect that you want to see the histogram.  For that, you want aggregation:

```
select date_part('day', cancelled_at - created_at) as activedays, count(*)
from databasetable
group by date_part('day', cancelled_at - created_at)
order by activedays;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *,DATE_PART('day', cancelled_at - created_at) as daysActive
FROM tableName
WHERE cancelled_at IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as
(
SELECT DATE_PART ('day', cancelled_at - created_at) as daysactive FROM yourTable WHERE
cancelled_at
IS NOT NULL 
)
select daysactive || ' day(s)'  as days_active from cte
```